# Netty Camel samples

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, netty

I'm a newbie to Netty.

I'm looking for some samples. (Preferably but not necessarity using Camel Netty Component and Spring)

Specifically a sample Netty app that consumes TCP messages.

Also how can I write a JUnit test that can test this netty app?

Thanks,
Dar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you still want to integrate with Camel.  I would first look at the [camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/netty.html) .  After that frustrates you, you will need to start experimenting.  I have one example where I created a Camel Processor as a Netty Server.  The Netty components work such that a From endpoint is a server which consumes and a To endpoint is a client which produces.  I needed a To endpoint that was a server and the component did not support that.  I simply implemented a Camel Processor as a spring bean that started a Netty Server when it was initialized.  The [JBoss Netty documentation and samples](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation) are very good though.  It is worthwhile to step through them.

Here is my slimmed down example.  It is a server that sends a message to all the clients that are connected.  If you are new to Netty I highly suggest going through the samples I linked to above:

```
public class NettyServer implements Processor {

private final ChannelGroup channelGroup = new DefaultChannelGroup();
private NioServerSocketChannelFactory serverSocketChannelFactory = null;
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

private String listenAddress = "0.0.0.0"; // overridden by spring-osgi value
private int listenPort = 51501; // overridden by spring-osgi value

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = (byte[]) exchange.getIn().getBody();
    // send over the wire
    sendMessage(bytes);
}

public synchronized void sendMessage(byte[] message) {
    ChannelBuffer cb = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(message);
    //writes to all clients connected.
    this.channelGroup.write(cb);
}

private class NettyServerHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

    @Override
    public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        super.channelOpen(ctx, e);
        //add client to the group.
        NettyServer.this.channelGroup.add(e.getChannel());

    }

    // Perform an automatic recon.
    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        super.channelConnected(ctx, e);
        // do something here when a clien connects.
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
        // Do something when a message is received...
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        // Log the exception/
    }

}

private class PublishSocketServerPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {

    @Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        // need to set the handler.
        return Channels.pipeline(new NettyServerHandler());
    }
}

// called by spring to start the server
public void init() {

    try {
        this.serverSocketChannelFactory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(this.executor, this.executor);
        final ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(this.serverSocketChannelFactory);
        serverBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new PublishSocketServerPipelineFactory());
        serverBootstrap.setOption("reuseAddress", true);
        final InetSocketAddress listenSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(this.listenAddress, this.listenPort);
        this.channelGroup.add(serverBootstrap.bind(listenSocketAddress));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

// called by spring to shut down the server.
public void destroy() {

    try {
        this.channelGroup.close();
        this.serverSocketChannelFactory.releaseExternalResources();
        this.executor.shutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

// injected by spring
public void setListenAddress(String listenAddress) {
    this.listenAddress = listenAddress;
}

// injected by spring
public void setListenPort(int listenPort) {
    this.listenPort = listenPort;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The camel release has a lot of examples but without a simple one for netty component.

Netty component can be use to setup a socket server to consume message and produce response back to the client. After some time of search on the web, I create my own  [tutorial using netty component in camel](http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2015/01/camel-netty-hello-world-simple-example.html) as a simple Camel-Netty hello world example to show:

1. Using netty component in camel to receive TCP message
2. Using POJO class to process the received message and create response
3. Sending response back to client.